# What is Event ID 33: SpellChecker in Windows 7 and 8 about?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, event-viewer

On newly installed Windows machines (Windows 8 Pro, Windows 7)
I've seen event id 33 regularly appearing in the event viewer with this message:

> Failed to add hardcoded change pair "aids -> aids" to engine: Not
>   implemented. The spell checker will still be available.

This are the Details of one of the Windows 8 machines:

```
- System 

  - Provider 

   [ Name]  Microsoft-Windows-SpellChecker 
   [ Guid]  {B2FCD41F-9A40-4150-8C92-B224B7D8C8AA} 

   EventID 33 

   Version 0 

   Level 2 

   Task 4 

   Opcode 0 

   Keywords 0x2000000000000000 

  - TimeCreated 

   [ SystemTime]  2013-03-07T09:49:45.428726200Z 

   EventRecordID 11089 

   Correlation 

  - Execution 

   [ ProcessID]  8164 
   [ ThreadID]  2624 

   Channel Application 

   Computer <my pc> 

  - Security 

   [ UserID]  <my user> 


- EventData 

  First aids 
  Second aids 
  hr -2147467263
```

For your information: All Windows versions were clean installed or some upgraded (in case of Windows 8).

Has anyone else seen this also? Because this 'hardcoded change pair' looks strange to me, unless somebody from Microsoft wanted to make a joke ;-)

Comment: The system spell-checker is new to Win8 and especially IE10 on both Win8 and Win7. I don't have any idea about that exact message though. Perhaps a diagnostic message that they forgot to remove? Doubt anyone knows the details except those involved with this feature at Microsoft.

Comment: hmmm, can't seem to find any additional information about event id 33 and spell-checker..